# How can a Solaris process read its own symbol table?

Tags: c++, solaris, loader, ld, dlopen

I have a Solaris process, which is a C++ application that is loaded by `ld` with a few `.so` libraries. This application has a function that gets a return address in the calling function and then tries to determine the name of the said calling function.

If I use `dladdr(3)` for that, it does not always put what I expect to see in Dl_info::dli_sname. It looks like it returns a name of a function that is not nearest below or at the pointer value. If I take the pointer value and look at the output of `nm`, I can match the value to the exact function I expect it to be.

I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve a symbol map for a process and let it search for the function name without using `dladdr(3)`. I am especially interested to get a symbol map not just for the executable itself but also for all `.so` libraries that it has loaded.

I'm running on Solaris10/SPARC and I'm using gcc 4.2.x.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it scanning the debug information? I remember XTank did something like that but it was a long time ago when I looked at the code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Martin. What I am talking about is more of an introspective of a process into its own symbol table. I know, I can use use `nm`, `objdump`, and even `pstack` to look at this information  but I am talking about retrieving this information by the process itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried a simple test using `dladdr()` on Solaris 10/SPARC (but caveats: GCC 3.4, straight C), and this works fine for me:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_name(char *name, void *addr);
void print_name_by_dladdr(void *addr);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    print_name("main", (void *)&main);
    print_name("print_name", (void *)&print_name);
    print_name("printf", (void *)&printf);
    return 0;
}

void print_name(char *name, void *addr)
{
    (void)printf("Getting name of function %s() at 0x%x\n", name, addr);
    print_name_by_dladdr(addr);
}

void print_name_by_dladdr(void *addr)
{
    Dl_info dli;
    if(!dladdr(addr, &dli)) {
        perror("dladdr()");
        exit(1);
    }
    (void)printf("  %s\n", dli.dli_sname);
}
```

Output:

```
Getting name of function main() at 0x10714
  main
Getting name of function print_name() at 0x10778
  print_name
Getting name of function printf() at 0x209b8
  _PROCEDURE_LINKAGE_TABLE_
```

This also works correctly if I write (for example)

```
    print_name("main", (void *)&main + 4);
```

You say you can resolve correctly against the output of `nm` so possibilities seem limited... are you certain that the return address is being derived or passed correctly to your resolver function? I guess you are using the [GCC builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) for this? I have tested `__builtin_return_address(0)` and this also works fine for me. If you are using the GCC builtins, did you call `__builtin_extract_return_address()` (see above page for details, mentions SPARC explicitly)? Can you post your code?

Can you stretch slightly to "process re-reading it's own binary/shared object files"? If so then [libelf](http://directory.fsf.org/project/libelf/) may be a way forwards. This is exactly what some of those utilities you mention are using, eg `nm`: http://cr.opensolaris.org/~devnull/6515400/usr/src/cmd/sgs/nm/common/nm.c.html

This [introductory article](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/elf.html) from sun.com might be of use (warning: article is 10 years old).

This isn't as nice as doing native introspection and it's odd that `dladdr(3C)` doesn't work :(

Alternative intermediate: have you tried the `RTLD_DL_SYMENT` flag to `dladdr1(3C)` (and then perhaps borrow from `nm.c` as above on the returned ELF sym)?

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed answer! I am using `__builtin_return_address(1)` to extract the return address in the caller. However, if I try to adjust the returned address via `__builtin_extract_return_address()`, I get a compilation error. GCC complains about `__builtin_extract_return_address` not being declared in the scope. At the same time, it happily compiles the sample app with `__builtin_return_address(1)`. I am confused now, how come it knows about one built-in and does not know about the other.

Comment: And I think you are completely right, I'm having this problem because of not using `__builtin_extract_return_address`. But I don't understand how GCC could be not aware of its own built-in...

Comment: According to comment in http://www.newae.com/6lowpan/fip/a00105.html `__builtin_extract_return_address` needs at least gcc 4.5. Time to upgrade...

Comment: Thanks again! I will need to explore more alternatives. Compiler upgrade in my environment is not a very viable option. I'm trying to re-invent a light-weight alternative to Dmalloc with a number of customizations to suit the type of projects I'm dealing with the most.

Answer (score 3):

a little late, but maybe still a help:
in elf-object files, there are generally 2 symbol tables:
.symtab and .dynsym
nm by default reads .symtab, use nm -D to read the .dynsym
table. dladdr (as well as the dynamic loader) do use the
.dynsym table. the .symtab table is more complete.
you can force all symbols being in the .dynsym table as
well using the -rdynamic linker flag. however, this slows
down linking significantly (e.g. in my current project by
aprox. 200ms). 
(nb: the above said referes to linux, but the symbol handling
works principly the same on sunos. command line options might
differ)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope I will get time to play with the ELF-file format in the next few weeks.