# C How to make static function to be contained in .dynsym?

Tags: c, gcc, static, compiler-construction, dladdr

### Background

I'm using [-finstrument-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078680/adding-printf-to-the-starting-of-all-functions-in-a-file/3078693#3078693) to trace function call in a c project.

I convert function address to function name by using **dladdr**. It successfully prase some address to function name, but some of them still cannot be parsed.

I've learned that [**ldaddr** only use dynsym table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7429333/9841324) which only contain **none static function**. static function contained in symtab.

### Question

Is there any way to make static function contained by .dynsym table without changing source code  ?